# Compensating for an iPhone Safari Rotation Bug

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, mobile-safari

Here are some steps to mess up the iPhone's rotation when in Safari

1. Holding the phone in vertical mode and navigate to google.co.cr with Safari
2. Rotate the phone horizontally
3. Rotate the phone vertically

The page is clipped as seen here:

[image: Clipped Page]

A simple horizontal swipe will bring it back.

This is not a problem with google.com, only with google.cr.co, but it illustrates the problem I am having.

Oddly enough, if you do the search from the Google Search box in the Safari Header, this resizes back to normal.

My web page has the same problem when following the same steps... it gets clipped.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not hitting this problem with iOS5

Comment: You are right. I am in Costa Rica, and it is redirecting to google.co.cr and it is having a problem with that. Obviously not a problem with iOS, but rather with the page. Can you duplicate it with co.cr?

Comment: I have the same problem on my web app! I think this is a good question and I would be very interested in its answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reset the viewport on orientation change.

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange',function() {
   if(window.orientation === 0) {
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
   }
},false);
```